# Origins of "pretty url"?

Tags: url-rewriting, friendly-url

This seems to be an official way to refer to it, as it's even got a [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_URL) on Wikipedia and some of Google's [ajax crawling documentation](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) calls it a pretty url as well. Heck, SO has 44 questions tagged [pretty-url](/questions/tagged/pretty-url) even. I do get that it is nicer looking to have `/post/1/` than `/post.php?id=1`, but who first called it a "pretty url"? When was the term popularized, and by who?

Comment: I'ver personally never heard 'pretty URL' and have instead extensively heard 'clean URL'... either way, tracking down an origin is likely going to be fruitless as I am sure it came about organically as so many things on the internet do.

Comment: Concern for pretty urls is not new. See: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html.en and http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990321.html. None of these sites mention the term "pretty url", though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this appelation became popular because of php and java cms which name there rewriting modules "Pretty Url".
Now it's nearly impossible to say which is the original author of this sentence !